# SET Request impossible with snmpSET and netsnmp lib

Tags: c++, snmp, net-snmp

i have an agent thanks to netsnmp library , its working fine for the Getrequest , I use MibIreasonning to do my test of get and set however I have a big problem for the set , when I do the snmp set i got no Response and the value dosent change  , with command line i use :
snmpset -v2c -cprivate 127.0.0.1:10181 1.3.6.1.4.1.4045.61005681.20.2.3.0.0 i 1
and i got : Timeout: No Response from 127.0.0.1:10181

and If i do snmpset in public I got : Error in packet , Reason noAccess

Here is my code if you can please help me :

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                         ValueOID
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-config.h>
#include <net-snmp/net-snmp-includes.h>
#include <net-snmp/agent/net-snmp-agent-includes.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <string>


int handle_AgentSNMP15 (
    netsnmp_mib_handler *handler,
    netsnmp_handler_registration *reginfo,
    netsnmp_agent_request_info *reqinfo,
    netsnmp_request_info *requests) {

    int value=0 ;

    switch (reqinfo->mode) {
        case MODE_GET:
        std::cout<<"GETSNMP15"<<std::endl;
         std::cout<<"get value "<<*(requests->requestvb->val.integer)<<std::endl;
            snmp_set_var_typed_value(
                requests->requestvb,
                ASN_INTEGER,
                (u_char*)&value,
                sizeof(value));
            break;
        case MODE_SET_RESERVE1:
            std::cout<<*(requests->requestvb->val.integer)<<std::endl;
        case MODE_SET_RESERVE2:
            value =  *(requests->requestvb->val.integer);
            std::cout<<"RESERVE2"<<std::endl;
            break;
        case MODE_SET_FREE:
            break;

        case MODE_SET_ACTION:
            std::cout<<"SETACTION"<<std::endl;
            value =  *(requests->requestvb->val.integer);

            break;

        case MODE_SET_COMMIT:
        std::cout<<"SETCOMMIT"<<std::endl;
            value =  *(requests->requestvb->val.integer);
            break;

        case MODE_SET_UNDO:
             break;

        default:
        {
            snmp_log(
                LOG_ERR,
                "Unknown mode (%d) in handle_dot1dBaseType\n",
                reqinfo->mode);
            std::cout<<"ERROR OTHER THAN GET";

            return SNMP_ERR_GENERR;
        }
    }

    return SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
}

void init_Value() {


    static oid AgentSNMP15[]={1,3,6,1,4,1,4045,61005681,20,2,3,0};



    netsnmp_register_scalar(netsnmp_create_handler_registration(
        "agentSNMP15",
        handle_AgentSNMP15,
        AgentSNMP15,
        OID_LENGTH(AgentSNMP15),
        HANDLER_CAN_RWRITE));



}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try to make your `value` variable at least static, or move it to global scope

Comment: how long is your timeout? I don't know what that OID is for, but maybe it triggers some action that takes an especially long time